# How to arrange divs one over another?

Tags: html, css, css-position, vertical-alignment

How can I arrange divs one over another?
I've tried `float`, `clear`, all positions but it doesn't work.

```css
img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

1 {
  position: absolute;
  clear: left;
}

2 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="1">
  <img src="//via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="imagine" width=300 height=300 />
  <p>Mos Goriot - Honore de Balzac<br> 10 lei</p><br>
</div>

<div id="1">
  <p><img src="//via.placeholder.com/220x300" alt="imagine" width=220 height=300 /> Peter Camenzind - Herman Hesse<br>15 lei</p>
</div>
```

Here's a screenshot of how it currently looks:

[image]

Comment: you want it like on the image or you want it to show one over the other?

Comment: Hi Octav. Welcome to SO. You should not post links in your SO question. You need to actually post the code that you've tried. Also, please read How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Moreover, you're trying to select ID 1 and 2 with 1 and 2 instead of using #1 and #2 on your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

1. [IDs must be unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).
2. To reference an ID in CSS, start with the `#` sign.

   > #id_value { style properties }

   See [CSS ID Selectors @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors).

---

Below, I'm using a "clearfix" method. For more reference, see:
[What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix)
[What methods of clearfix can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/what-methods-of-clearfix-can-i-use)
[Chris Coyier on Clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

```css
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.entry {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}

img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry group">
  <img src="//via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="imagine" width=300 height=300 />
  <p>Mos Goriot - Honore de Balzac<br> 10 lei</p>
</div>

<div class="entry group">
  <img src="//via.placeholder.com/220x300" alt="imagine" width=220 height=300 />
  <p>Peter Camenzind - Herman Hesse<br>15 lei</p>
</div>
```